# jquery validate does not show error message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I've searched similar questions and have found no joy. The validation works, in terms of its logic in the send function, but the span following the validated element is not showing the error message when invalid. I've even tried passing in errorPlacement, but the only thing that works is if I specifically set it like so

```
$("#msgvalid").text($("#msg").attr("data-val-required"));
```

The relevant html is

```
<form id="frmSend" style="margin-top:15px">
Add Comment:
<div>
<textarea id="msg" data-val="true" data-val-required="The comment cannot be blank." placeholder="Enter comment here" style="height:50px;width:300px"></textarea>
<span id="msgvalid" class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="msg" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="send();" class="btn-default" style="margin-top:10px">Send Comment</button>
</form>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

and the relevant javascript is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function send() {
$("#frmSend").validate();
if (!$("#frmSend").valid()) { return false; }
alert("Would send");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Move the `.validate()` method out of your `send()` function.  It's only used for **initializing** the plugin on your form and should be called once when the page is loaded.  Second, the plugin automatically creates the error element, so you would **not** create this element yourself in advance.

Comment: Also, every element considered for validation **must** have a `name` attribute.  Finally, if you're using `unobtrusive-validation`, then you cannot call the `.validate()` method yourself, since `unobtrusive` constructs and calls that method automatically.  http://jsfiddle.net/5f2xn3zk/

Comment: @Sparky Thanks. Using the name attribute was the key. I admit I did read that somewhere, but I thought I had other pages where the error message displays without there being a name attribute, so I ignored it. But now that I look again I see they do in fact have the name attribute. Sigh.

Comment: The [official documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-markup-recommendations) and the [Wiki Tag page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) are pretty clear about the `name` requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have a `name` attribute on every input element considered for validation...

[Documentation:](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-markup-recommendations)

> The `name` attribute is "required" for input elements, the validation plugin doesn't work without it.